# Make a scrollabe input type text of select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 in place of search box.

Here i'm using to load countries values like this

```
 <label class="description"> Countries </label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Comma Separated Countries..." class="save_check" 
    style="overflow: auto; width: 208px; margin: 5px 0px 5px; border-style: solid;" id="countries" />
```

What happens here is whenever i select values in this, the height of this input type text goes on increasing which goes beyond its parent div height, I wan't it to be scrollable as the parameters increases. In `select2.css` i changed `overflow: auto` but none works.

Comment: You should set a jsfiddle, hard to see your problem without working sample.

Comment: Roasted how can i load external select2.min.js and select2.js in jsfiddle. I'm newbie in jsfiddle

Comment: You have to add it from external resources field on left, using a CDN server, see this jsfiddle already have select2.js loaded: http://jsfiddle.net/platypusman/xDUUg/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the height to the element for the `overflow: auto` to work.

```
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices {
 height: 70px; 
 overflow: auto;
}
```